# Reactjs this.setState() fails on server

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Using Reactjs with Meteor and my component's `setState()` results in an error and only on the staging server, not on my local machine.

This is the error

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'banners.list': e@http://example.com/09d8a88b6d8e1e9a36c24cbe031f383a60bbb044.js?meteor_js_resource=true:196:27322
require<.node_modules.react.lib["ReactCompositeComponent.js"]</S._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext@http://example.com/09d8a88b6d8e1e9a36c24cbe031f383a60bbb044.js?meteor_js_resource=true:61:7658
require<.node_modules.react.lib["ReactCompositeComponent.js"]</S._renderValidatedComponent@http://example.com/09d8a88b6d8e1e9a36c24cbe031f383a60bbb044.js?meteor_js_resource=true:61:7826
require<.node_modules.react.lib["ReactCompositeComponent.js"]</S.performInitialMount@http://example.com/09d8a88b6d8e1e9a36c24cbe031f383a60bbb044.js?meteor_js_resource=true:61:2297
require<.node_modules.react.lib["ReactCompositeComponent.js"]</S.mountComponent@http://example.com/09d8a88b6d8e1e9a36c24cbe031f383a60bbb044.js?meteor_js_resource=true:61:1553
require<.node_modules.react.lib["ReactReconciler.js"]</a.mountComponent@ht[…]
```

The code responsible for this error is

```
const that = this;
Meteor.call('banners.list', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`Error fetching banner info with ${err.reason}`);
  }
  console.log(data)
  that.setState({
    isBannerPrepared: true,
    banners: data,
  });
});
```

Pretty basic. Once I remove the `that.setState()`, it works fine. `data` is not null.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Meteor and React combined, but could you not just do `this.state = { isBannerPrepared: true, ... }`.  It's for the initial state right?

Comment: `this.state = {...}` goes in the `constructor` but I need to start fetch after user clicks a button

Answer (score 0):

why you would do this...this way?
as I know you can manipulate props in react from the meteor. Meteor updates the props and you in the react events update the state.

Comment: yes, in most cases, passing on props from parent to child is the recommended way but my use case required for my child component to be able to fetch it's own data, irrespective of who the parent is. Also it would be more appropriate for this to go under comments because it's not really an answer.

Comment: sure but you can have a 'child' which is container + component. You will then always attach via container. I use this approach with success.

Comment: Child component with container? Interesting. What benefits does the container component combination as a child have over using state to store data?

Comment: as I know wise people say that state isn't a place to store data. Only the crucial few elements. Props are for that or redux way.
Second thing is why the approach I stated is nice?
Let's look at a parent component
it has <child something={veryimportantvalue} />
than in child's container you do
let niceData = Mongo.find({aaa:props.something})
and then push it as props to your component.
Voila! Everything works, you follow 'wise people' way, you have access to everything from props....and minimongo ;)